# Why does Speedtest CLI upload fail for US mobile carriers?

Tags: mobile, embedded-linux, lte, speed-test

I'm trying to run [Speedtest CLI](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) on an embedded Linux device using LTE in the US but the upload fails:

```
Speedtest by Ookla

     Server: North Central Telephone Coop - Lafayette, TN (id = 4895)
        ISP: Verizon Wireless
    Latency:    49.88 ms   (6.93 ms jitter)
   Download:     9.23 Mbps (data used: 9.8 MB )                               
     Upload: FAILED                                            
[error] Cannot write:
```

This works fine if I put the same SIM card in a Wifi access point then connect to it, so it's something to do with the setup of the device. But it works fine in other countries with local carriers.

Comment: To the person who voted to close - it's taken me several weeks to find the solution to this problem so I'm sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is that Linux defaults the [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) to 1500 but US mobile carriers prefer a lower value:
https://www.digi.com/support/knowledge-base/recommended-mtu-mru-settings-on-cellular-networks

```
Recommended values are:
* AT&T 1420 bytes
* Verizon 1428 bytes
* Others 1430 bytes
(PPP interface default is 1500 bytes)

To ensure our routers work well on all carriers. set the PPP interface local and remote MRU to 1420.
```

Changing the MTU to 1420 fixed the problem:

```
ifconfig <Interface_name> mtu <mtu_size> up
```

Full instructions here: https://linuxhint.com/how-to-change-mtu-size-in-linux/